# NodeJS/ReactJS File Upload to Digital Ocean Spaces

Tags: node.js, reactjs, aws-sdk, digital-ocean

A lot of the different answers on SO seem to have different ideas about how to go about this...I've been trying to piece them together and get this working, but no luck.

Basically, my `console.log("uploading....")` and `console.log("uploaded....")` show up, but nothing is actually getting uploaded. No errors display, either.

`server.js`:

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

//aws setup
const s3 = new aws.S3();
aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: "MY_SECRET",
  accessKeyId: "MY_KEY",
  region: "us-east-1"
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "filehub",
    key: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
  })
}).array("upload", 1);

app.post("/files/upload_aws", (req, res, next) => {
  upload(req, res, function(err) {
    console.log("uploading....");
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("uploaded....");
  });
});
```

And on the front end, in case it's help to anybody, though this part seems to be working just fine:

```
  handleAWSFile = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("clicked");

    axios
      .post("files/upload_aws")
      .then(res => {
        this.props.handleSnackBar("File added to AWS");
      })
      .catch(res => {
        this.props.handleSnackBar("File NOT added to AWS!!");
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few different things going on here.

I have my region labeled differently for Digital Ocean. Instead of directly putting the region into the aws.config update, I have:

```
aws.config.update({
accessKeyId: process.env.SPACES_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
secretAccessKey: process.env.SPACES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

// Set S3 endpoint to DigitalOcean Spaces
const spacesEndpoint = new aws.Endpoint('nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com');
const s3 = new aws.S3({
endpoint: spacesEndpoint
});
```

Also, I include a line for the acl in my multer storage function:

```
// Change bucket property to your Space name
const upload = multer({

    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'your-space-name',
        acl: 'public-read',
        key: function (request, file, cb) {
            console.log(file);
            cb(null, file.originalname);
        }
    })
}).array('file', 1);
```

It's also really important to keep track of whatever name you put into that array bit at the end there. In my case, I have "file". I'll use that in my POST request.

Here's my sample Postman upload:
[Postman Sample Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qxal.png)